# Trouble copying hair modifiers from one object to another, keeping the same result

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, hair

I'm having trouble copying hair modifiers from one object to another, keeping the same result

I can copy the modifiers from one curve system to another, the properties stay the same, but the results are wildly different.

The objects are nearly the same size, both are UV'd, and scale / rotation have been applied.

I've also tried duplicating the curve system and attaching it to the new mesh, but it maintains the old shape.

Any thoughts?